# Are there any fan-created campaigns for Shadows of Brimstone?

Tags: house-rules, shadows-of-brimstone

I'd like to get into Shadows of Brimstone, but I've heard that there's a part during setup where you configure how hard the adventure is going to be.  I'm a little bit put off by that.  I worry that, when/if I win, it'll feel like I only won because I made the game too easy.

One thing I liked about Pathfinder Adventure Card Game is that it comes with a little campaign: it tells you to play these scenarios, in this order, with these special rules attached to each one.

Is there anything like that (perhaps fan-created) for Shadows of Brimstone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both City of the Ancients and Swamps of Death (the two base game sets available) include an adventure book.

Each adventure book features 12 missions, the first six of which are the same in both books, and then the last six are specific to the setting. They can be played through as a campaign or as individual missions, supposedly getting harder as they progress (I have only played the first three so far so can't really comment on the difficulty of later missions).

Regarding the setup phase where you determine the "difficulty" of the game, it is not a choice of easy/medium/hard etc. It is a scale based on the number of heroes, which defines the general number/difficulty of monsters and the number of revives you can use when heroes are knocked out. This scale is more about balance for the number of players than a way to actually increase/decrease the difficulty.

You can of course choose to make things harder or easier by changing the number of revive tokens or the Threat deck you draw from, but so far I have found the suggested difficulty to be reasonably well balanced and have lost just as often as I have won, although I have so far only played with 1, 4 or 5 players so can't really speak about the balance of 2, 3 or 6 player games, but the progression seems reasonable.

Comment: In fact, I'm not sure that the missions in the Quests Book are designed to get harder. A suggested way of choosing the quest to play is drawing a world card then rolling for a quest in the given world (that's how I've played so far) which means that you could start with the last quest... The initiation quest is indeed the 1st one from the Mine world with adaptations to avoid the advanced rules in the first game. In fact, the Campaign feel comes more IMHO from the leveling up system: that's what determines from which decks you draw the monsters and if they have special abilities.

Answer (score 1):

There's a fan-made campaign (7 scenarios) which has been posted on BGG and has good reviews... I didn't tried it myself (yet) as I enjoy the randomness of picking a quest from the game at random and just going there for now.

It was designed by Eric Laurent and is called *One Way Ticket*
It requires *Swamp of Death* as the party ends up in Jargono.

You can find the presentation by the designer and a link to all the files here:
http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1341036/sob-complete-campaign-7-missions-new-tiles-new-car/page/1

Answer (score 1):

*HexCrawl* (by Sid Rain) looks more like an alternative way to play the game than a Campaign. It introduces a map where the party travels from mines to towns and back with various events taking place during travels.

It includes a campaign system:

> A campaign system that takes your Heroes from start to finish and provides an actual end-goal for your posse to strive for. The plan is that a full campaign will encompass all 8 levels of a Hero and their development.

This probably requires more investment and a regularly meeting group but might fill the bill.

Here's a link to the BGG forum post where the designer hosts the project:
http://boardgamegeek.com/article/16952329